# Is there a way to show a functions activity on webpage

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a flask web application where a function is performing some task on a List. Now after iterating over the list and doing some operation with each element in the list, a new page is rendered. But the Operation being performed on each element takes some time. So, I want to display an output on the same web page from where that function was called, while the function is running as an which elements operation is complete. And after finish only new page is loaded. Please give me some idea how can I do that.

Comment: your best bet is to try storing this output somewhere with fast access, set another endpoint to get this data and then get data to webpage using some ajax in javascript...

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to do this is to have these 2 APIs

1. A "Job acceptor" POST API that accepts the request, starts the processing and returns a Http Status code `202(Accepted)`. The response contains a URL that you can hit to get the status of the application
2. A "Status Poller" API that you can do a GET on to get the status of the operation on the list. The UI can then show progress based on the status returned.

Note that the status can be anything from a abstract "In progress" to a concrete "92% complete". Internally the 2nd API has a way to get the amount of progress on the operation on the list

**Reference**
https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/

Quoting the relevant bits from the above link

> If you submitted a long-running asynchronous job to a REST API then
>   API can return the result like this:

HTTP STATUS 202 (Accepted)

```
{
    "task": {
        "href": "/api/company/job-management/jobs/2130040",
        "id": "2130040"
    }
}
```

> Now user agent can send HTTP GET request to URI
>   /api/company/job-management/jobs/2130040 periodically for completion
>   status of the job. The response of above API will inform the current
>   status of actual scheduled operation.